# Laravel Auth Redirect to Previous Page

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am attempting to create a single page like application with Laravel 4. When the user arrives at the site, they should be prompted to log in. Once the user logs in, the view (not the URL) will switch and the user will be able to see information as if they are authenticated.

My HTML (if authroized should show "Auth" in `h1`, if not, it shows login form)

```
<div class="container">
        @if(Auth::check())
            <h1>Auth</h1>
        @else
            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'login', 'method'=>'post')) }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
                        {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'example@test.com')) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
                        {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    {{ Form::submit('Log In', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif
    </div>
```

Controller

```
class SiteController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function postLogin() {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password)))
        {
            return Redirect::route('index');
        }
    }

}
```

My user model is the default that ships with Laravel 4. As of now, I am passing the `Auth::attempt` and getting the `return Redirect::route('index');`, but the `@if(Auth::check())` doesn't seem to be firing. Instead it continues to show me the log in form. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here, but you need to be sure what's happening, it looks like your authenticated session is not sticking, but to be sure you could:

```
<?php

class SiteController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        Log::info('index - authed: '. Auth::check() ? 'yes' : 'no');

        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function postLogin() {
        $email = Input::get('email');

        $password = Input::get('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password)))
        {
            Log::info('postLogin - attempt successful');

            return Redirect::route('index');
        }

        Log::info('postLogin - error on attempt');
    }

}
```

And then check your logs:

```
php artisan tail
```

Comment: I found the issue! I had my database column set to `userId` instead of `id` and it was throwing everything off. Thank you!